# Are "Favorites" and edits synced with Photos for Mac/iOS?

Tags: ios, photos

I'm using the latest version of Photos on both of my iMacs, my iPhone, and two iPads.

I'm also using iCloud for storage and syncing.

So far - everything seems to work - when I take a photo on my iPhone, it shows up on all my Macs and devices.

However - what happens when I edit a photo in Photos on one of my iMacs? Does the edited photo show up on my other Mac and other devices? Also - if I "favorite" a photo in Photos - should that show up on my other devices?

Comment: so did you try it and what happened ?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349975/are-favorites-in-the-photos-app-suppose-to-sync-between-devices/360318#360318

Answer (score 1):

According to this Support article from 2016 the answer depends on how you sync:

- If you import photos from an iOS device to Photos over USB, the favorite status will not sync (!)
- If you use iCloud Photo Library to sync across devices the favorite status will sync.

Source: [Apple Support - Q: iOS Photos to OSX Photos favorites sync](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7591080?answerId=30335354022#30335354022)

FWIW this is totally offensive and horrible, I can hardly believe it. I just did an import of 3k images and apparently have lost all of my favorite statuses. What a mess.