# Are favorites in the Photos app suppose to sync between devices?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, photos.app

I use Apple Photos on my Macs and on my iOS devices. I can flag photos via the Heart icon as favorites, but in my case they are not synced between devices.

Is this a bug, or is this meant to be like this?

ps: I saw the question [Are "Favorites" and edits synced with Photos for Mac/iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198686/are-favorites-and-edits-synced-with-photos-for-mac-ios), but it neither attracted answers nor is it it particular current - that's why I ask this here and now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will (or should) sync between devices *if you are using iCloud Photo Library*, otherwise, e.g. when syncing just the PhotoStream, favourites do not sync.

I just tested this on a device running iOS 12.1.3 and macOS Mojave 10.14.3 by favoriting a photo in the iOS photos app, and not only did the photo appear in the Favorites album in Photos.app on Mac, the Favorites album was automatically created in both places. (I don't use Favorites, but they do seem to work for me.)

According to [Apple's Support article for iCloud Photo Library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264#edits), edits do indeed sync between devices. I also confirmed this just now by cropping a photo on my Mac, and watching the cropped photo appear on my iOS device.

NB: if you are trying to sync favorites between devices using a hardline sync such as iTunes, I am unable to describe what the correct behavior for that is, as I don't have a setup to test it with currently, nor could I find any information on Apple's support website.

Comment: Thanks Valashtar. I had exactly the scenario in mind you tested. It does not work for me, **but I do not have the iCloud Photo Library enable** - only Photo Stream.

Comment: Update: Now I have enabled the iCloud Library and now everything syncs for me too.

Answer (score 6):

According to this Support article from 2016 the answer depends on how you sync:

- If you import photos from an iOS device to Photos over USB, the favorite status will not sync (!) but edits should (at least they do now, but not back then, I've tested this)
- If you use iCloud Photo Library to sync across devices the favorite status will sync along with the edits.

Source: [Apple Support - Q: iOS Photos to OSX Photos favorites sync](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7591080?answerId=30335354022#30335354022)

FWIW this is totally offensive and horrible, I can hardly believe it. I just did an import of 3k images and apparently have lost all of my favorite statuses. What a mess.

Comment: I'm in the same boat.. thank you for your answer

Comment: Yes, I would call this absolutely hideous. Apple really cares about my pictures of my family and what I think of them, as long as I do exactly what they tell me and don't try to "think different" within their own micromanaged landscape by using options available to me that are guess what, to my preference!

Comment: Making lifetime Apple customers hate them, one OS update at a time. This is a huge violation of privacy for no reason at all, except to flash the bird at their users (use iCloud, where your private data is unencrypted and available for harvesting, or the Apple experience will gradually degrade to unusable).